# Подскажите, какие технологии или библиотеки следует изучить

Tags: c++

Есть приложение, в котором при определенных событиях издается один и тот же звук-уведомление, сильно отличающийся от остального фона. Нужно сделать так, чтобы отправлялось системное уведомление каждый раз когда возникает данный звук.

Напрямую влезть в код этого приложения и написать отправку уведомления я не могу, поэтому мне нужно понять с помощью какой технологии можно прослушивать звуки с конкретного приложения и анализировать на возникновение конкретного нужного мне звука.

Comment: Как прослушать аудиопоток конкретного приложения зависит от ОС и языка. И решить проблему можно разными путями, например, используя приложения, имитирующие аудиовыход, или, если на windows, открыть аудиопоток через winapi и подключить к нему приложение. А для анализа вам может подойти алгоритм быстрой кросс корреляции. Берёте кусочек аудио и проводите его через FFT, делайте также со образцом звука. После перемножайте спектральные ряды и применяйте к нему обратный FFT (iFFT). В полученной кривой будет зависимость корреляции двух сигналов от цикличного смещения, остаётся только найти максимум.